# search through child node (firebase) check if username exists?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im creating an android app with a register activity, im able to add data to my firebase database, but im having trouble with querying the existing data. basically im trying to do a simple username search that will toast the user notifying them that the username already exists (so they can then create a unique one) im sure i am making a simple mistake. I have created a separate node which is just existing usernames (not sure if this is wise or not haha). my code still adds the user even if the username exists. any help in the matter would be AWESOME! thanks everyone!

I have tried using dataSnapshot.exists and played around with the nodes etc. (as i mentioned earlier with adding a seperate username node)

```
{
  "all usernames" : {
       "-LbEvUXcT9Mc3V7awfBz" : "qwerty",
       "-LbEwLUAwQsnlwFeya5o" : "ted"
   },
   "users" : {
       "CgnIejgGw0QvNAGbY5LWx6o17Us1" : {
            "userEmail" : "ted@gmail.com",
             "userName" : "ted"
     }
   }
 }
```

in case my image does not show up my node set up as shown above:

```
username = etUsername.getText().toString();

    myRef.child("users").child("userName").equalTo(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"username Exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

                String userId = mAuth.getUid();

                userEmail = etEmail.getText().toString();
                username = etUsername.getText().toString();


                UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(username, userEmail);

                myRef.child("users").child(userId).setValue(userProfile);
                myRef.child("all usernames").push().setValue(username);
                createUser();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });[database structure][1]





[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjfq5.png
```

Comment: The pseudo-JSON makes it hard to see what's going on. Please replace it with a snippet of the actual JSON (as text, **no** screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thanks i will do it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter on a property you first need to order on it. You're trying to do that with:

```
myRef.child("users").child("userName")
```

But this is literally translated into `/users/userName`, which doesn't exist.

To order each child node under `/users` on its `userName` property (and then filter it), you need:

```
myRef.child("users").orderByChild("userName").equalTo(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to :

```
myRef.child("users").child("userName").child(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapShot.getValue(String.class) ==null)
              {
                    //username doesn't exist
                    //do something 
              }
            else
              {
                     //username exist
                    //do something
              }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

});
```

Also, I think you should change your database structure to

```
username:{
      billy:true,
      name2:true
   }
```

in order to store more than one username, since in current scenario you are overriding the value.

Comment: Thanks Saurav! I will give this a try!

Comment: Will be waiting for your response

Comment: Heading to the library first thing in the morning ;)